Drag-and-drop action is being interpreted as a click, bypassing the confirmation dialog
We’ve got an EF6 MVC3 codeFirst-site. And recently i learned that if you click it, the confirm dialog works fine, but if you click and try to undo it by drag the link somewere and let go, you would assume that the click is cancelled. That works fine on my dev-environment but in production the link is really clicked, bypassing the confirmation dialog?
  <a href="@Url.Action("something","somecontroller")?listId=@Model.ListOfCLists[i].CListId" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want this?');" class="btn btn-xs menulink" download><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span> Download</a>

 

Here is another example, click-drag is not making a click on localhost, but in production it is interpreted as a click
@Html.ActionLink("Välj", "BuyTicket", new { ticketTypeID = 11 }, new { @onclick = "return confirm('Vill du använda 124 poäng?')", @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs orange pull-right" })

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Inspect the actual HTML for the page in both environments. The presence of the development environment would make absolutely no difference, what matters is which browser is used. I could not reproduce the behavior you describe. I had a test anchor pointing at google.com with a confirmation and tested the "click and drag off", no browser tested either triggered the click event or followed the href link when dragged off before releasing. Beyond that a difference in OS/settings during the production testing, especially if the behavior is seen on a different machine/device.

Thank you so much for trying to help me. For some reason, the incorrect behavior stopped even in production environment, so the error is fixed for now anyway ;)

For some reason, the incorrect behavior stopped, so the error is fixed for now ;)
